# Getting Data from Azure SQL database in Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I'm having problems getting data from my AZURE SQL database. My code does get data, but not all of it. The intention is that the function needs to take all users in wicht the age is X (f.ex.:20)and return an array with those users. Right now the code just return the first user it finds on the database. I am using Azure-functions in which I use Insomnia to test the result.
Here is the function that gets the data from the DB:

```
function testfunc(age){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
        let result = [];
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM [datingschema].[user] where age = @age'
        const request = new Request(sql, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log("beforeerr");
                console.log(err) //ingen err - så det godt nok!
                console.log("aftererr");
                reject(err);
            }
        })
        request.addParameter('age', TYPES.Int, age)
        request.on('row', (columns) => {
            columns.forEach(column =>{

                result.push(column.value)
            })
            resolve(result)
        });
        
    
        connection.execSql(request)
    })
}
```

Here is a part of my code in Azure-function where I call for the function. There should be no errors in there as it works fine when I need to get only one user:

```
const db = require('../database/db');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try {
        await db.startDb(); //start db connection
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting to the database", error.message)
    }
    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            await get(context, req);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            await post(context, req);
            break
        default:
            context.res = {
                body: "Please get or post"
        };
            break
    }
}

async function get(context, req){
    try{
        let id = req.query.age
        let user = await db.testfunc(id)
        context.res = {
            body: user
        };
    } catch(error){
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: `No User - ${error.message}`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say that the problem should be related to my "testfunc" function in the "request.on" part. I just can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: COuld you please check if your database has some users with same age?

Comment: Jim Xu, yes it does. At least 3 or 4. I also tried using other values such as "gender". The SQL Query works in the DB console, so the problem shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens, because you resolve your promise after you have read the first row. Consider the following:

```
function testfunc(age){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
        let result = [];
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM [datingschema].[user] where age = @age'
        const request = new Request(sql, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log("beforeerr");
                console.log(err) //ingen err - så det godt nok!
                console.log("aftererr");
                reject(err);
            }
        })
        request.addParameter('age', TYPES.Int, age)

        // This is executed multiple times, once for each row
        request.on('row', (columns) => {
            let row = []

            // Accumulate the columns to a row
            columns.forEach(column =>{
                row.push(column.value)
            })

            // Don't resolve here. Instead append to result..
            // resolve(result)
            result.push(row)
        });

        // This is executed once, when the query has completed
        request.on('done', () => {
            // .. and resolve here
            resolve(result)
        })
    
        connection.execSql(request)
    })
}
```